# How to make a cutomized query to Solr with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data-solr

I am trying to retrieve some data I stored before from Solr. This is my model.

```
    @SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "images")
        public class Imagen {
            @Id
            @Field
            private String id;
            @Field
            public String origin_url;
            @Field
            public String[] predominantColor;
            @Field
            public double predominantColor_hue;
```

If I want to get all the "Imagen" where `predominantColor_hue` is near of the value I enter, how can I make a customized query for that? Because I just tried to use the

```
public interface ImagenRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Imagen, String> {
    Imagen[] findByPredominantColor_hue(double predominantColor_hue);
}
```

Also tried this

```
Imagen[] findByPredominantColor_hueIsLessThanAndPredominantColor_hueIsGreaterThan(double predominantColor_hue1, double predominantColor_hue2);
```

but I get this error:

```
No property hue found for type String! Traversed path: Imagen.predominantColor.
```

Maybe if I can make a custom query I can say to Solr that I want the `Imagen` which have a `predominantColor_hue` close to the one I want to compare. Maybe +5 and -5. But, how can I make that query? Already googled a lot and nothing found. Thanks and SORRY for my English!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions,

1. Rename your `predominantColor_hue` field to `predominantColorHue`, because `_` has a special meaning in spring-data queries.
2. Your Query should be like this

   ```
   List<Imagen> findByPredominantColorHueGreaterThanAndPredominantColorHueLessThan(double predominantColor_hue1, double predominantColor_hue2);
   ```

If you want to get values near x, Now you can use this method like this

```
findByPredominantColorHueGreaterThanAndPredominantColorHueLessThan(x-5, x+5)
```